# Convert a queue to the stack?

Tags: c++, stack, queue

I have a queue with n elements in it and the front is at `0`. I need to create a stack of these numbers with `0` at the top.

It can only be done with *EnQueue*, *DeQueue*, *Push*, and *Pop*, and constant storage. I dont need an answer so much as an idea of how I could approach this problem.

Please don't answer this for me, but just try to understand I'm new at programming and could just use an idea of what is a way this can be done.

- Is it a Towers-of-Hanoi-like approach?
- Does that only use a constant storage?

This isnt for homework, I just need some advice on how to proceed.  My first idea, reversing the queue and then pushing it did not work. I even tried sketching out other situations with no avail. Then I wondered if dequeueing and pushing them all, then popping and enqueueing them all, then dequeue and push again.

- Is this efficient?
- Does this use constant storage?

I am still learning fundamental programming concepts. Please be nice! :)

Comment: Can you use a second, temporary stack?

Comment: You said "My first idea, reversing the queue and then pushing it did not work."  How did you reverse the queue with only enqueue and dequeue operations on it?

Comment: ....why exactly. It had been my first idea, but I realized I couldn't utilize the reverseList method I'd written earlier today because the question specifically wants you to only use enque, dequeu, etc. So thats why it didnt work - its not an answer

Comment: @caleb Would that take up "constant" storage? If I can get it to take up "constant" storage than yes. But I'm not sure what "constant" means in this context. Could I use a stack even if it is dynamically created? Wouldnt the items placed in the temp stack also some how be dependent upon n?

Comment: See my answer, it should provide you with enough information to solve  the problem on your own, otherwise there is a sample implementation with description in a spoiler if you are interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What am I facing?

The biggest problem you are facing is that your two containers aren't directly compatible with each other.

A *queue* is normally a FIFO<sup>1</sup> container, while a *stack* is LIFO<sup>2</sup>. This means that you cannot just copy the data in sequential order from your *queue* to your *stack*, since that will make the elements appear in the *"wrong"* order (following your description).

Another problem is that there is no good way (performance wise) to reverse a *queue*. A *queue* is a one-way container, internally an element only has to know about the next element in line, not about the previous one. This means that you cannot iterate through the *queue* starting at the back, and that iteration always is *O(n)*.

The same problem is with your *stack*.

> The things described earlier put together makes this quite a tedious problem, though there are solutions they aren't always the most straight forward.

---

#### Hints on how to solve this issue..

You'll need some sort of intermediate state to store your elements, or could we use the LIFO/FIFO properties of our containers to our advantage?

Below is an implementation which does what you want, if you don't want to know the answer to your question *don't* hover with your mouse over this gray area.

It will require some additional storage since space for an extra element will be allocated during copying from one container to another.. this is **inevitable**, though the storage is constant.

<sup>Remember that the *copy-initialization* can be optimized by using *rvalue-references* and *move* in C++11.</sup>

> <sup>*Can't seem to get syntax highlighting working inside a spoiler..*</sup>
>  
>  Sample implementation can be found  [here](http://ideone.com/A4ucq).
>  
>  It takes advantage of the fact that a *queue* is FIFO and *stack* LIFO, by copying the data *queue to stack*, then *stack to queue* and finally *queue to stack* again we have effectively reversed the order of elements in a way that will match your description.

---

<sup>**footnotes**</sup>
   <sup><sup>1.</sup> FIFO = First In First Out</sup>
   <sup><sup>2.</sup> LIFO = Last In First Out</sup>

Answer (score 4):

DeQueue everything from Queue, immediately Pushing each element to Stack.  Now Pop everything from Stack, immediately EnQueueing to Queue.  What's in Queue now?

Presuming your Queue and Stack hold fixed sized items, the above *ahem* subroutine certainly only uses constant additional storage: Only storage for 1 item is needed as each item transits from Queue to Stack or vice-versa.

**Edit**: As you point out, my subroutine reverses the content of the Queue.  Having done so, it is fairly simple to drain the Queue into the Stack again to get the desired outcome.

And, as you point out, this requires transferring `3n = O(n)` items, where `n` is the initial size of the Queue.  Could you do better?  I don't believe so, or at least not significantly.  In some sense, without even a counter (which would take `O(log n) > O(1)` extra storage), the only reasonable thing to do is drain the queue into the stack or vice versa.

Comment: Queue backwards. Then I could dequeue them all and push them onto the stack in the desired order. This is actually what I thought of doing as I sat here and typed this question. It didnt really occur to me until I wrote the question so I asked it anyway. Is that right? though ? Is it efficient? I believe its 3n so it would be O(n) and use no additional storage?

Comment: Efficient?  Errm, I don't think anyone in their right mind would do something like this in production code.  Nor would s/he be likely to insist on the restrictions you've placed on the problem, either.  But it is asymptotically linear time.  And (asymptotically) that's the best you can do.

Comment: Thanks! Your edit clarified it for me. I forgot about having to store the dequeued node before pushing it does already require constant storage. Oh im so happy, what makes me feel so great about this answer is that its actually something I thought of right before I posted literally I as I was typing the question. It feels so much better now that I wasnt thinking that incorrectly. :)

Comment: Why "asymptotically linear"?  It's plain-old linear. Each element gets processed exactly three times, whether you have 2 elements, 200 elements, or 2 billion elements.

Comment: Though now I'm curious if it would be possible to reverse the contents of a queue given only another (initially empty) queue and constant storage.  It's certainly possible with two stacks (which can be rigged together to simulate a Turing machine), but two queues?  Maybe if you were given a special data item that could be placed into the queues, but was guaranteed not to be in them initially?  But this is just idle thought.

Comment: @Managu - you can reverse a queue using only another queue along with additional constant storage of a location for a 'set-aside' element (the one you want to 'reorder' at a particular step) and a counter to keep track of how many items are already reordered.

Comment: @Managu: a counter is certainly constant space.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, there's a matter of computational model.  In the RAM model, data items are integers, and so can hold counters.  I had in mind a model where each data item is finite; say each item is a byte.  In such a model, it takes `O(log n)` space to hold a counter that can count up to `n`.

Comment: @Managu: I see what you're saying as well.